# VBA post request

Tags: vba, post

I am trying to send a request for a specific store, but nothing comes out. Tell me, please, what not to do? The price for this should be 15 899.

```
Sub Macros1()
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim name As String
XMLPage.Open "POST", "https://hoff.ru/catalog/?articul=80295933", False
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "User -Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Host", "hoff.ru:443"
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "current_location_id=1780"
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "current_city=714"
XMLPage.send
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
name = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("product-new-price")(0).innerText
Cells(4, 1) = name
End Sub
```

Comment: Something is wrong with that site @Vsevolod S. Try your above code and you will see that it is working smoothly now and generating the result you wished to have `15 899`. Even if, you kick out all the `setRequestHeader` portion from your request or even try `GET` instead of  `POST`, all are the same. You will get the same result. At least, I'm having so.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to send A "POST" request? Try sending "GET" request instead to collect the price you are after. Here is how you can do:

```
Sub Fetch_Price()
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With HTTP
        .Open "GET", "https://hoff.ru/catalog/?articul=80295933", False
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set post = HTML.getElementsByClassName("product-new-price")(0)
    [A1] = post.innerText
End Sub
```

Output:

```
16 999руб.
```

When you wish to parse the product price of `store 714`, you need to send a `POST` request to this `https://hoff.ru/ajax/get_delivery_price.php` along with appropriate parameters. The `FormData` which should be passed with the `POST` request are huge. Moreover, there are some `json` content (within those parameters) which are a bit complicated to handle.

However, your best bet is to go for InternetExplorer:

```
Sub Fetch_Price()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, elem As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://hoff.ru/catalog/?articul=80295933"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With

    Do: Set post = HTML.getElementsByClassName("header-city-name j_header_city_name")(0): DoEvents: Loop While post Is Nothing
    post.Click

    HTML.getElementById("city-714").Click
    Do: Set elem = HTML.getElementsByClassName("product-new-price")(0): DoEvents: Loop While elem Is Nothing

    [A1] = elem.innerText

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Output:

```
 15 899руб.
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: In that case,I need the price for store 714,and the price he had 15 899

Comment: Oh I see!! So, where did you mention which price you wanna parse? Your question is still damn vague. Can you tell me the location of `store 714`? Top, bottom, left, right, middle ------? Btw, there are several sites where price of different product updates, so I thought the one I've tried is the one you are after.

Comment: On this website https://hoff.ru/catalog/?articul=80295933
At the upper left when choosing a store "Ростов на Дону" I need to extract this value,for this store,the price should be 15 899

Comment: What is it in English `Ростов на Дону`?

Comment: city Rostov-on-don

Comment: Thank you very much for help.
Tried your option, everything works.
I also thought about IE, but it is much longer handles(

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use ServerXMLHTTP60.

```
Sub Macros1()
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim name As String
XMLPage.Open "POST", "https://hoff.ru/catalog/?articul=80295933", False
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Host", "hoff.ru:443"
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "current_location_id=1780"
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "current_city=714"
XMLPage.send
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
name = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("product-new-price")(0).innerText
Cells(4, 1) = name
End Sub
```

Your cookies aren't being set properly (checked this by comparing a response with one done in postman, another application that can make POST requests).

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that XMLHTTP60 really allows you to set them, so use ServerXMLHTTP60 instead.

Comment: This bug is interesting, any links?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234486/prb-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader-method-and-cookies

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d20fe371-46cc-42d3-a452-1698310be3f5/xmlhttp-fails-to-send-cookies-from-a-client-issue-seems-not-fixed?forum=xmlandnetfx

Comment: ok, second page says "If you really need to set cookie in the request header, please use ServerXMLHTTP " so I think you should advise OP.

Comment: I think I should have taken like one more minute to actually test ServerXMLHTTP lol... updated.

Comment: cool, sending cookies is on my list of things to do, you've saved me some time (in the future).

Comment: Thank you very much!!Clicked through Cody G.
put MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP and it worked!